# Equivalent of ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

Tags: dbt

i’m having a hard time understanding possibility of achieving “on conflict do nothing” behavior with DBT.
I have a predefined PostgreSQL table with an unique two-column index - `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING btree (col1, col2);`. Now i want to make an incremental model on the top of this table.
The problem is that I want to ignore all insert conflict while building the model.
With PostgreSQL it looks smth like `insert into table (....) values(....) on conflict(col1,col2) do nothing`;

I’ve seen ‘unique_key’ and ‘incremental_strategy’ options, but they are not much of a help.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

As PostgreSQL only supports the default incremental_strategy = 'merge' you do not have to specify this in your setup.

I am not completely sure if I understand your question correctly. But first, you need to specify your incremental model in the config settings.

Secondly, as far as I understand your issue, you can specify your concern in the pre_hook configurations as shown below:

```
{{

config(    
  materialized = 'incremental',   
  unique_key = 'id',
  pre_hook="""
    {% if is_incremental() %}
      pre_hook="<sql-statement>" | ["<sql-statement>"]
    {% endif %}  
    """
}}
```